# Use ENUM in EJS view

Tags: node.js, ejs

I have a db with a "Requests" table which has a field "status" as INTEGER, I fetch its data in my index and show the different requests.

```
app.get("/", async (req, res) => {
    try {
        db.open();
        const requests = await db.getRequestsByUserID(req.user.ID);
        db.close();
        res.render("index.ejs", { requests: requests });
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(`Error while showing requests: ${e}`);
        db.close();
        res.render("index.ejs", { name: req.user.first_name, requests: [], error: "Cannot show requests" });
    }
});
```

I want each request status to be shown (in my EJS view) as a String.
For example I have status value 2: i want to print "Accepted".

I've created a status.js like so:

```
module.exports = {
    1: "Pending",
    2: "Accepted",
    3: "Rejected",
    4: "Cancelled"
}
```

I figured out you can get the value in the server.js like so:

```
const STATUS = require("./public/js/status");
console.log(STATUS[2]) // this prints "Accepted"
```

How do I get the same value when I show each request in my EJS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, now you can pass it to the view:

```
const STATUS = require("./public/js/status");
//...
res.render("index.ejs", { requests, STATUS });
```

and then dynamically use the key to access the value, for example:

```
<% requests.forEach(request=>{ %>
    <div>status: <%= STATUS[request.status] %></div>
<% }); %>
```